# preg_match_all only return the first array with index 0 and not one with index 1

Tags: php, arrays, search, preg-match-all

**1**. I'm trying to match some IDs from a from with url and return all IDs.

The code is as follow.

**The string is something like this**

```
"gfdgfds.php?id=67f8d4fd6d4&gfddgfds.php?
id=67f8d4f6d4&gfddgfds.php?id=67f8d4f6d4&gfdsgfds.php?id=67f8d4f6fdd4&"
```

**Pattern**

```
$pattern = '/p?id=[0-9A-Za-z]*/';
```

**CODE**

```
preg_match_all($pattern,$input,$matches);   
    //var_dump(count($matches));
     if( count($matches) > 0 ) {
         var_dump($matches);
        //return $matches[1];
     } else {
        die('No matches found.');    
    }
```

But from the above when I do var_dump($matches) I get.

```
array (size=1)
  0 =>
```

And I was expecting to get

```
array (size=1)
      0 =>array()
      1 =>array() // So I can use this.
```

What am I missing here, thanks.

**2**. Also, I'd like the $pattern = "'/p?id=[0-9A-Za-z]*/'" to match "php?id=value", not just any id=value.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using regular expressions for parsing URL parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regex you can use `parse_url` function but don't know exactly what is your expected output but instead of `preg_match_all` use `preg_match` with following regex

```
(.php\?id=(\w+))
```

So your code looks like as

```
preg_match("/(.php\?id=(\w+))/",$your_string,$matches);
```